# font-lock limits ignored in anchored matchers

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

I think I might have found a bug in GNU Emacs but I want to check my understanding first.

In [Search Based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification) it is possible to specify a `function` as a `matcher`. It must obey the contract

> it receives one argument, the limit of the search; it should begin searching at point, and not search beyond the limit. It should return non-nil if it succeeds, and set the match data to describe the match that was found. Returning nil indicates failure of the search.

In addition, for multi-line matches it is possible to extent the region to be fontified by adding a routine to `font-lock-extend-region-functions` that in-place updates the `font-lock-beg` or `font-lock-end` variables (these variables are **not** visible in a `function matcher`).

Indeed, I have confirmed that if I extend the region in a `font-lock-extend-region-functions` then the `limit` does increase in my `function matcher`!

However, if we use an an anchored matcher, having the form `(matcher . anchored-highlighter)`, where the `anchored-highlighter` is a `function`, my custom `font-lock-{beg,end}` regions are ignored!

Is there something I need to do so that anchored matchers receive the calculated regions or are they only designed to extend to the end of the current line by default?

Comment: I don't know much about font lock, but: How are you triggering font lock?  Fontifying a whole buffer/region, or in response to making an edit to a buffer, or in response to scrolling (JIT lock)? Are you using a test framework?

Comment: @CroadLangshan I don't understand your question. `font-lock` is a "we call you API" that's documented in quite some detail in the docs I linked from the question. I think this one needs a font lock expert :-)

Comment: Sure, and maybe you looked at the code too, but the reason I asked is that looking at the code, I have a suspicion that may be relevant, and I thought I might give it a try and see if I can understand why that happens -- which may lead to an answer (even though you're asking about intent).  As for what I meant: as I understand it, for example: if one visits a file, the whole buffer may not be immediately fontified, but only (roughly) the visible region.  On the other hand if you're say running `font-lock-fontify-buffer`, JIT lock presumably won't be used.

Comment: ...when I say lead to an answer, I guess I likely mean "comment" :-) -- because I'm no authority on font-lock -- but maybe a comment that might answer your question ;-)

Comment: thanks @CroadLangshan, but this is a bit more subtle than that sort of thing... it's a very specific, isolated, case of using a function matcher vs an anchored function matcher, not a general font-lock region problem. It's being invoked correctly. I can see the larger region when the anchor is called, but it is reduced in the anchored matcher. I'm currently reading through `font-lock-default-fontify-region` and `font-lock-fontify-keywords-region` to confirm my suspicion that this is a bug.

Comment: now onto `font-lock-fontify-anchored-keywords`...

Comment: Yes I think I understood that fommil.  My guess, nevertheless, is that you may see the issue only in particular circumstances, because it looks like `font-lock-extend-region-functions` is not always called, at least not in a straightforward way (for example by `font-lock-extend-jit-lock-region-after-change`).  Over and out

Comment: thanks @CroadLangshan I think I figured it out by following the source code... I added an answer. It seems the documentation just wasn't clear on this point. I can understand the actual (and intended) behaviour now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you have found the answer to your question already, by looking at the source code.

The behaviour is in fact documented. The doc string of the variable `font-lock-keywords` contains the following, in the section describing MATCH-ANCHORED:

> The limit of the
>   MATCHER search defaults to the end of the line after
>   PRE-MATCH-FORM is evaluated.  However, if PRE-MATCH-FORM returns
>   a position greater than the position after PRE-MATCH-FORM is
>   evaluated, that position is used as the limit of the search.

Technically, "returns a position" means that the expression evaluates to an integer value.

For example, the following makes the inner search use the match found in the outer search (which may span multiple lines if `font-lock-multiline` is non-nil):

```
(my-outer-search-function
 (my-inner-search-function
  ;; pre-match-form
  (progn
    (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
    (match-end 0))
  ;; post-match-form
  nil
  (1 'font-lock-variable-name-face prepend)))
```

Comment: argh, I guess I should remember to read the `C-h v` help as well as the Lisp manual in future...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've tracked the issue to `font-lock-fontify-anchored-keywords` which is called with a `limit` parameter, but then `limit` is mutated very intentionally to the limit generated by the outer matcher... so I think this is NOT a bug, but just very different behaviour to what I expected.

```
(defsubst font-lock-fontify-anchored-keywords (keywords limit)
  (let ((matcher (nth 0 keywords)) (lowdarks (nthcdr 3 keywords)) highlights
    (lead-start (match-beginning 0))
    (pre-match-value (eval (nth 1 keywords))))
    (if (not (and (numberp pre-match-value) (> pre-match-value (point))))
        (setq limit (line-end-position))
      (setq limit pre-match-value)
      ...
```